# Session Timeout in JSF

Tags: session, jsf-2

i have developed a web application in JSF2.0 and Primeface 3.4 the application mainly is used for doing Image Processing operations like increase/decrease brightness contrast etc.. all this operations are achieved using Javascript hence all the operations are carried out at client side during this period there is no server trip involved.

The only server trip that is made is during the tab switch to fetch the data from the server(Tabs are implemented using primefaces tabview component).

In my web.xml i have defined a session timeout of 10mins. Now the problem is that when a user is performing the image processing activites on particular tab and since no server trip is involved during this period the server assumes that the user is ideal(obviously) as a result the session timeouts and user is redirected to login page.

So how do i avoid this.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Session is maintained at application server level and if you want to keep the session active, you can send an AJAX message to a server side JSF page, every few minutes when the processing is continuing in client browser. The JSF page can be a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

in your web.xml try setting javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD to client.this will solve your problem